# Replace pattern in string with value from a ruby array

Tags: ruby

I have a string like this

```
"base: [_0x3e63[241], _0x3e63[242]],
            gray: [_0x3e63[243], _0x3e63[244], _0x3e63[245], _0x3e63[246], _0x3e63[247], _0x3e63[248], _0x3e63[249], _0x3e63[250], _0x3e63[251], _0x3e63[252]],
            red: [_0x3e63[253], _0x3e63[254], _0x3e63[255], _0x3e63[256], _0x3e63[257], _0x3e63[258], _0x3e63[259], _0x3e63[260], _0x3e63[261], _0x3e63[262]],
            pink: [_0x3e63[263], _0x3e63[264], _0x3e63[265], _0x3e63[266], _0x3e63[267], _0x3e63[268], _0x3e63[269], _0x3e63[270], _0x3e63[271], _0x3e63[272]],
            grape: [_0x3e63[273], _0x3e63[274], _0x3e63[275], _0x3e63[276], _0x3e63[277], _0x3e63[278], _0x3e63[279], _0x3e63[280], _0x3e63[281], _0x3e63[282]],
            violet: [_0x3e63[283], _0x3e63[284], _0x3e63[285], _0x3e63[286], _0x3e63[287], _0x3e63[288], _0x3e63[289], _0x3e63[290], _0x3e63[291], _0x3e63[292]],
            indigo: [_0x3e63[293], _0x3e63[294], _0x3e63[295], _0x3e63[296], _0x3e63[297], _0x3e63[298], _0x3e63[299], _0x3e63[300], _0x3e63[301], _0x3e63[302]],
            blue: [_0x3e63[303], _0x3e63[304], _0x3e63[305], _0x3e63[306], _0x3e63[307], _0x3e63[308], _0x3e63[309], _0x3e63[310], _0x3e63[311], _0x3e63[312]],
            cyan: [_0x3e63[313], _0x3e63[314], _0x3e63[315], _0x3e63[316], _0x3e63[317], _0x3e63[318], _0x3e63[319], _0x3e63[320], _0x3e63[321], _0x3e63[322]],
            teal: [_0x3e63[323], _0x3e63[324], _0x3e63[325], _0x3e63[326], _0x3e63[327], _0x3e63[328], _0x3e63[329], _0x3e63[330], _0x3e63[331], _0x3e63[332]],
            green: [_0x3e63[333], _0x3e63[334], _0x3e63[335], _0x3e63[336], _0x3e63[337], _0x3e63[338], _0x3e63[339], _0x3e63[340], _0x3e63[341], _0x3e63[342]],
            lime: [_0x3e63[343], _0x3e63[344], _0x3e63[345], _0x3e63[346], _0x3e63[347], _0x3e63[348], _0x3e63[349], _0x3e63[350], _0x3e63[351], _0x3e63[352]],
            yellow: [_0x3e63[353], _0x3e63[354], _0x3e63[355], _0x3e63[356], _0x3e63[357], _0x3e63[358], _0x3e63[359], _0x3e63[360], _0x3e63[361], _0x3e63[362]],
            orange: [_0x3e63[363], _0x3e63[364], _0x3e63[365], _0x3e63[366], _0x3e63[367], _0x3e63[368], _0x3e63[369], _0x3e63[370], _0x3e63[371], _0x3e63[372]]"
```

_0x3e63 is a ruby array with the values.

```
_0x3e63 = ["#f783ac", "#faa2c1", "#fcc2d7", "#ffdeeb", "#fff0f6", "#862e9c", "#9c36b5", "#ae3ec9", "#be4bdb", "#cc5de8", "#da77f2", "#e599f7", "#eebefa", "#f3d9fa", "#f8f0fc", "#5f3dc4", "#6741d9", "#7048e8", "#7950f2", "#845ef7", "#9775fa", "#b197fc", "#d0bfff", "#e5dbff", "#f3f0ff", "#364fc7", "#3b5bdb", "#4263eb", "#4c6ef5", "#5c7cfa", "#748ffc", "#91a7ff", "#bac8ff", "#dbe4ff", "#edf2ff", "#1864ab", "#1971c2", "#1c7ed6", "#228be6", "#339af0", "#4dabf7", "#74c0fc", "#a5d8ff", "#d0ebff", "#e7f5ff", "#0b7285", "#0c8599", "#1098ad", "#15aabf", "#22b8cf", "#3bc9db", "#66d9e8", "#99e9f2", "#c5f6fa", "#e3fafc", "#087f5b", "#099268", "#0ca678", "#12b886", "#20c997", "#38d9a9", "#63e6be", "#96f2d7", "#c3fae8", "#e6fcf5", "#2b8a3e", "#2f9e44", "#37b24d", "#40c057", "#51cf66", "#69db7c", "#8ce99a", "#b2f2bb", "#d3f9d8", "#ebfbee", "#5c940d", "#66a80f", "#74b816", "#82c91e", "#94d82d", "#a9e34b", "#c0eb75", "#d8f5a2", "#e9fac8", "#f4fce3", "#e67700", "#f08c00", "#f59f00", "#fab005", "#fcc419", "#ffd43b", "#ffe066", "#ffec99", "#fff3bf", "#fff9db", "#d9480f", "#e8590c"]
```

I cannot find a way to retrieve from the string `_0x3e63[xxxxxxx]` replacing it with the right value....

Comment: Why do you have such string in the first place?

Comment: _"... replacing it with the right value"_ – what is the right value? Your array contains 97 elements, but the indices in your string are much higher.

Comment: Use [`String#gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a block.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String#gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a block.

Assuming your input string is stored in the variable `input`, the following code does the replacement and displays the result:

```
puts input.gsub(/_0x3e63\[(\d+)\]/){|s| _0x3e63[$1.to_i]}
```

*(The array `_0x3e63` you posted in the question does not contain enough values to have indices like `247` or `251` but the code works nevertheless.)*

The code is very simple. The regular expression `/_0x3e63\[(\d+)\]/` matches any string that starts with `_0x3e63[`, continues with one or more digits (`\d+`) and ends with `]`.

For each match the block is executed and the value returned by the block is used to replace the matched piece of the original string.

The replacement uses `$1` (that contains the sub-string that matches the first capturing group) as an index into the array `_0x3e63`. Because the value of `$1` is a string, `.to_i` is used to convert it to a number (required to be used as index in the array).

Answer (score 0):

We are given:

```
str =<<~END
base: [arr[6], arr[3]],
gray: [arr[0], arr[4], arr[1], arr[5]],
red:  [arr[2]]
END
  #=> "base: [arr[6], arr[3]],\ngray: [arr[0], arr[4], arr[1], arr[5]],\nred:  [arr[2]]\n"
```

and

```
arr = ["#f783ac", "#faa2c1", "#fcc2d7", "#ffdeeb", "#fff0f6", "#862e9c",
       "#9c36b5"]
```

We can perform the required replacements by using [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a regular expression and [Kernel#eval](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-eval):

```
puts str.gsub(/\barr\[\d+\]/) { |s| eval s }
base: [#9c36b5, #ffdeeb],
gray: [#f783ac, #fff0f6, #faa2c1, #862e9c],
red:  [#fcc2d7]
```

The regular expression preforms the following operations:

```
\b     # match a word break (to avoid matching 'gnarr')
arr\[  # match string 'arr['
\d+    # match 1+ digits
\]     # match ']'
```

[Rubular](https://rubular.com/r/LyS4t6iZUd6xvU)

One must be cautious about using `eval` (to avoid launching missiles inadvertently, for example), but as long as the matches of the string can be trusted it's a perfectly safe and useful method.